# Class decorator instance int variables?

Tags: python

```
def classDecorator(aClass):
    def variables(self):
        for variable in self.__dict__:
            if isinstance(variable, int):
                yield variable
    setattr(aClass, 'variables', variables)
    return aClass

@classDecorator
class myClass:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = myClass()
    x.a = 2
    print(str(x.variables()))
```

This decorator should add a method to the class that returns an iterator of the instance variables of type int of the instance it is invoked by, but if I run the program it prints this:

```
<generator object classDecorator.<locals>.variables at 0x011385D8>
```

Why?

Comment: That's the iterator. You have to iterate over it to get the actual attribute names. Try `print(list(x.elencaVariabili()))`.

Comment: `print(str(x.elencaVariabili().__next__()))` would print the first int, to print all the ints you need to iterate over the function, e.g. `for some_int in x.elencaVariabili()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

Comment: @chepner it prints an empty list []

Comment: @rotemtal it gives me StopIteration error

Comment: that's likely since variables cannot be ints, iterating over a dictionary is iterating over it's keys, since in the dictionary representation of a class the variables are the keys, no key would be an instance of int (e.g. you wont have `self.1 = x`). if you want variables whose assignment is an int you should iterate over values, or just use the line `if isinstance(self.dict[variable],int)`

Comment: Indeed: if you want a list of the values, `for variable in self.__dict__.values()`:. If you want a list of the names, `if isinstance(self.__dict__[variable], int):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop `for variable in self.__dict__` will give you the *names* of the variables (as a sequence of strings). To get the values, can use this:

```
for var, value in self.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(value, int):
        yield var
```

In addition, use `list()` to collect the values yielded by the iterator, as shown in the comments:

```
print(list(x.variables()))
```

Comment: Could also use a `yield from` :) `yield from (var for var, value in self.__dict__.items() if isinstance(value, int))`

Comment: Let's keep it comprehensible, @flakes ;-)

Comment: Is that a pun for me using a comprehension expression? lol

Comment: Huh, no that was an accident... Well spotted! :-D